# Backbone boilerplate: "this.model is undefined"

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm a backbone newbie, so I'm sort of fumbling on getting an app set up. I'm using the backbone-boilerplate (https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) and github-viewer (https://github.com/tbranyen/github-viewer) as a reference, though when running I seem to be getting a "this.model is undefined".

Here is my current router.js:

```
define([
    // Application.
    "app",

    //Modules
    "modules/homepage"
],
    function (app, Homepage) {
        "use strict";

        // Defining the application router, you can attach sub routers here.
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                var collections = {
                    homepage: new Homepage.Collection()
                };

                _.extend(this, collections);

                app.useLayout("main-frame").setViews({
                    ".homepage": new Homepage.Views.Index(collections)
                }).render();
            },

            routes:{
                "":"index"
            },

            index: function () {
                this.reset();
                this.homepage.fetch();
            },

            // Shortcut for building a url.
            go: function() {
                return this.navigate(_.toArray(arguments).join("/"), true);
            },

            reset: function() {
                // Reset collections to initial state.
                if (this.homepage.length) {
                    this.homepage.reset();
                }

                // Reset active model.
                app.active = false;
            }

        });

        return Router;
    }
);
```

And my homepage.js module:

```
define([
    "app"
],
function(app){
    "use strict";

    var Homepage = app.module();

    Homepage.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function(){
            return {
                homepage: {}
            };
        }
    });

    Homepage.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Homepage.Model,

        cache: true,

        url: '/app/json/test.json',

        initialize: function(models, options){
            if (options) {
                this.homepage = options.homepage;
            }
        }
    });

    Homepage.Views.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: "homepage",
        el: '#mainContent',

        render: function(){
            var tmpl = _.template(this.template);

            $(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));

            return this;
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(this.options.homepage, {
                "reset": function(){
                    this.render();
                },

                "fetch": function() {
                    $(this.el).html("Loading...");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return Homepage;
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**Update:** After much googling (you should see how many tabs I have open), I *think* I made a little bit of headway, but still no luck. I updated my router to have the following:

```
app.useLayout("main-frame").setViews({
    ".homepage": new Homepage.Views.Index()
}).render();
```

I made a number of modifications to my homepage.js module to now look like this:

```
define([
    "app",
    ["localStorage"]
],
function(app){
    "use strict";

    var Homepage = app.module();

    Homepage.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: function(){
            return {
                homepage: {}
            };
        }
    });

    Homepage.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("Homepage.Collection"),

        refreshFromServer: function() {
            return Backbone.ajaxSync('read', this).done( function(data){
                console.log(data);
                //save the data somehow?
            });
        },

        model: Homepage.Model,

        cache: true,

        url: '/app/json/test.json',

        initialize: function(options){
            if (options) {
                this.homepage = options.homepage;
            }else{
                //this.refreshFromServer();
            }
        }
    });

    Homepage.Views.Index = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: "homepage",
        el: '#mainContent',

        initialize: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.collection = new Homepage.Collection();
            this.collection.fetch().done( function(){
                self.render();
            });
        },

        render: function(){
            var data = this.collection;

            if (typeof(data) === "undefined") {
                $(this.el).html("Loading...");
            } else {
                $(this.el).html(_.template(this.template, data.toJSON()));
            }
            return this;
        }
    });

    return Homepage;
});
```

As you can see, I have localStorage code but commented out for now because I just want to get everything working first. The ultimate goal is to have an initial call that loads data from a JSON file, then continues afterwards using localStorage. The app will later submit data after the user does a number of interactions with my app.

I am getting the main view to load, though the homepage module isn't populating the #mainContent container in the main view.

I did all of the googling that I could but frustrated that it's just not sinking in for me. Thanks again for looking at this and any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your class hierarchy is a bit wonky here. Your instance of `Homepage.Collection` is actually assigning a `homepage` property out of options, for instance. Then you pass an instance of `Homepage.Collection` into `Homepage.Views.Index` as the `homepage` option... It's a bit hard to follow.

That said, it seems to me your problem is simply that you aren't supply a `model` option when you construct your `Homepage.Views.Index`:

```
new Homepage.Views.Index(collections)
```

`collections` doesn't have a `model` property, and thus I don't see how `this.model.toJSON()` later on in the view can have a model to access. Basically, you seem to want `Homepage.Views.Index` to handle a *collection* of models, not just one. So you probably need a loop in your `render` function that goes over `this.collection` (and you should change your construction of the view to have a `collection` option instead of `homepage` option).

If I'm missing something here or I'm unclear it's because of this data model oddness I mentioned earlier. Feel free to clarify how you've got it reasoned out and we can try again :)

Comment: Oy, thank you for looking at this! I still have a bunch of sorting out to do, and that original collection of models was in the example code which I stripped down to just one collection. That said, it's till not working, will try to include some code shortly...

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ended up working through a bunch of stuff, so I posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857166/view-loading-before-main-layout-is-loaded

Answer (score 1):

This example code you have is a little bit confusing to me, but I think the problem lies in the following two lines of code:

```
".homepage": new Homepage.Views.Index(collections)
$(this.el).html(tmpl(this.model.toJSON()));
```

It looks like you pass a collection to the view, but in the view you use this.model, hence the error "this.model is undefined", since it is indeed undefined.

If you aren't in any rush, may I suggest that you start over. It seems you are trying too much too quickly. I see that you have backbone, requirejs (or some other module loader), and the boilerplate, which is a lot to take in for someone new to backbone. Trust me, I know, because I am relatively new, too. Maybe start with some hello world stuff and slowly work your way up.  Otherwise, hacking your way through bits of code from various projects can get confusing.